# How can do these on one line, I seem to having trouble getting it to work

Tags: powershell

```
$NameMatches = $Prices | Where-Object 'name' -EQ $sub.OfferName 
$TermMatches = $NameMatches | where-object 'itemCode' -match $Term   
$BillingFreqMatches = $TermMatches | where-object 'ItemCode' -match $BillingFreq
```

These 3 lines work, but any syntax I use to put them on one line returns no results.

Comment: Unless I missed something, this should work. 

`$Prices | Where-Object { $_.'name' -EQ $sub.OfferName -and $_.itemCode -match $Term -and $_.ItemCode -match $BillingFreq } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for this:

```
$Prices | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -eq $sub.OfferName -and $_.itemCode -match $Term -and $_.itemCode -match $BillingFreq
}
```

Note that you cannot use *Comparison Statement* when doing multiple conditions, you must use *Script block*. See [Description section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2#description) from the Cmdlet's MS Docs.